# How to remove white spaces between word and spefic token?

Tags: awk, sed

I want to clean my code which looks sort like this.

```
for(i=0; i < max; i++){
    test = 5 + test                     ;
    if (test == 10)
         printf("HELLO WORLD\n")          ;
}
```

How do you remove the spaces between "test" and ";" without de-formatting the other lines?

Edit: I also want to remove every other spaces before a semicolon.

I tried something with this:

```
sed 's/;.*$/;/p' $FILE
```

but it also removes the spaces from the beginning of the line until the first word.

I prefer the answer to use something like awk or sed. 
Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow, please show us sample Input_file and expected output in CODE TAGS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This would remove all blank characters (spaces or tabs) before a `;` at the end of the line:

```
sed 's/[[:blank:]]*;$/;/' file.c
```

I assume that you also want the spaces before the semicolon on the `printf` line to be removed.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you for the reply.

Answer (score 1):

To *remove the spaces between "test" and ";" without de-formatting the other lines* using awk:

```
$ awk '{sub(/test +;/,"test;")}1' file
for(i=0; i < max; i++){
    test = 5 + test;
    if (test == 10)
         printf("HELLO WORLD\n")          ;
}
```

If the `test +;` appears elsewhere than in the end of the line you could throw into the regex: `/test +; *$/`

**Edit** To remove all the space before `;`s (and after) using awk:

```
$ awk '{sub(/ +; *$/,";")}1' file
for(i=0; i < max; i++){
    test = 5 + test;
    if (test == 10)
         printf("HELLO WORLD\n");
}
```

Comment: Typically a `sed` job I feel though :-)

Comment: @sjsam So I figured too but after your comment I compared the speeds of Tom's and my solution to a million lines of `    test = 5 + test                     ;`. awk ran real time 1.614s and sed 5.066s.

Comment: Sorry. In my first draft i didn't specified that I also want to remove al the other occurrences of spaces before the semicolon. Thank you anyway for your reply./